# Privoxy redirect blacklist sites to whitelist site

Tags: wifi, raspberry-pi, privoxy, wifi-hotspot

For my application, I need a WiFi hotspot that has the entire internet blocked except for one website. I am thinking about using a Raspberry Pi configured as a WiFi hotspot and using Privoxy.

Privoxy has the capability to whitelist and blacklist sites (in my case there would be just one whitelisted site, with everything else blocked).

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/16957/whitelist-internet-filter

What I now need is for any blocked site to be redirected to the the whitelisted site. An additional bonus is for the white listed site to appear immediately once users have connected to the WiFi, just like the captive portal on a WiFi hotspot.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Install `privoxy`
2. Define an IP which the daemon will be listening on (for example 192.168.0.1)
3. In proxy settings (wifi), set this IP (so in our example 192.168.0.1) as a proxy-server.

Regarding whitelisting I think, the best solution is to block all sites and then whitelist only the ones you need. So, open `user.action` file and then first block all sites:

```
{ +block }
/
```

Then we can whitelist urls we need

```
{ -block}
.example.com
.unix.stackexchange.com
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Considering that someone looking for this solution is likely not very familiar with `privoxy`, would you consider editing your post to include locations of the relevant config files they would need to modify?